# Top-fixed navbar jittering on Android browsers while scrolling?

Tags: android, html, css

Visit a webpage that uses a navbar that's fixed to the top using an Android device.

[Example 1: The Next Web](http://thenextweb.com/)

[Example 2: A test page I built (You'll have to scroll down a little bit to get fixed navbars)](http://andrew-oh.com/testpage/)

Is it only me, or does anyone else see the navbar "jitter" when you scroll the page? Is there anything you can do to fix it? I see the issue on my Samsung Galaxy S3 running Jelly Bean with Chrome, Dolphin Browser HD, and the stock browser. For some reason, I cannot replicate the issue with my Asus Transformer TF101 tablet.

Comment: If by jitter you mean a delay in showing the header when you scroll down.

Comment: I mean the contents of the navbar jump around a few pixels when scrolling

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I know this question is old, but have you found a solution? Thanks!

Comment: @NOPENOPENOPE : I think I did end up fixing it! I don't remember exactly how though... Could you put up an example so I could look at it?

Comment: @MisterOh Yeah, what did you want an example of? Just the HTML and CSS that goes with the navbar?

Comment: @NOPENOPENOPE yeah or even just a quick jsfiddle